# I need to find the confidence intervals for proportions using stratified data

Tags: sas, proc

I'm trying to report estimates of proportions of subjects of a stratified random sample

I've tried every website I can find for SAS proc surveymeans, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
data b;
set Data;
keep id texting section;
run;

proc surveyselect data=b out=samp_b method=srs n=(15,12,10,8)  
    seed=123;
strata section;
run;

proc surveymeans data=samp_b;
strata section;
weight SamplingWeight;
var texting;
run;
```

I should get confidence intervals for the strata, but they are not showing up. Also I need confidence intervals for the proportions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of SAS/STAT you are using, but per SAS/STAT 9.2 Proc Surveymeans documentation pages, you can do one or both of the following:

1) Add the relevant statistics keywords to the `proc surveymeans` statement

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveymeans_sect007.htm

> In the PROC SURVEYMEANS statement, you also can use statistic-keywords to specify statistics for the procedure to compute. Available statistics include the population mean and population total, together with their variance estimates and confidence limits. You can also request data set summary information and sample design information.

The available statistics keywords are listed and described on these pages:
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveymeans_a0000000238.htm
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveymeans_sect007.htm#statug.surveymeans.smeanskeys

So, to print the 95% two-sided confidence interval for the mean, you would add `CLM` to the end of your Proc Surveymeans statement.

2) Save the Statistics table with confidence intervals to a separate SAS dataset with an additional `ods output Statistics=MyStat;` statement, per [these](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveymeans_sect005.htm) instructions.